# vba to load automatically when workbook opens

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have code a

```
Private sub Workbook_open()
 ListBox1.AddItem "2017"
 ListBox1.AddItem "2018"
 ListBox1.AddItem "2019"
 ListBox1.AddItem "2020"
 ListBox1.AddItem "2021"
 ListBox1.AddItem "2022"
 ListBox1.AddItem "2023"
 ListBox1.AddItem "2024"
 ListBox4.AddItem "0%"
 ListBox4.AddItem "10%"
 ListBox4.AddItem "20%"
 ListBox4.AddItem "30%"
 ListBox4.AddItem "40%"
 ListBox4.AddItem "50%"
 ListBox4.AddItem "60%"
End Sub
```

But when i open the workbook the listbox doesn't populate automatically. Is there a way to load the listbox items automatically without having a command button?

Comment: check your excel security settings to see if they will allow for code to be executed on open?

Answer (score 1):

I've found defining which sheet the listbox is on makes this work

The `.clear` at the start is to prevent multiple of the same option being created.

```
Sub Workbook_open()

Sheet1.ListBox1.Clear
Sheet1.ListBox2.Clear

With Sheet1.ListBox1
    .AddItem "2017"
    .AddItem "2018"
    .AddItem "2019"
    .AddItem "2020"
    .AddItem "2021"
    .AddItem "2022"
    .AddItem "2023"
    .AddItem "2024" 
End With

With Sheet1.ListBox4
    .AddItem "0%"
    .AddItem "10%"
    .AddItem "20%"
    .AddItem "30%"
    .AddItem "40%"
    .AddItem "50%"
    .AddItem "60%" 
End With

End Sub
```